# Saving multidimensional Javascript array to server-side CSV

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, csv

I'm trying to save a multidimensional Javascript array as a CSV file on the server. So far, my code creates the CSV file, but the file doesn't contain my array, and I'm not sure why.

(where outputData is established)

```
function dataSave(){
outputStr = JSON.stringify(outputData);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "csvout.php",
    data: outputStr,
    dataType: 'html',
});}
```

csvout.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<?php    
$array = json_decode($_POST['outputStr']);
$file = fopen("out/data.csv","w");
foreach ($array as $line){
    foreach ($line as $item){
        fputcsv($file,explode(',',$item));
        }
    }

fclose($file); 
?>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The data is an array of arrays like this one-- it's data obtained from the client, who is participating in a scientific experiment. Everything is a string.

```
0: "tuba.mp3"
1: "prac"
2: "1"
3: "0"
4: "type1"
5. "500"

0: "clap.mp3"
1: "main"
2: "0"
3: "0"
4: "type1"
5. "300"

[...]
```

Comment: Could we have an example of how your array may look like?

Comment: Re: using fputcsv and explode at the same time, I'm a little confused by this answer because there is example code at this link that uses both and it seems to work: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fputcsv.asp

Comment: Add "jQuery" to your question tags; you may get more relevant help if you specify what your code is about and it will result in less "down-votes".

Comment: Printing it to console reads Array [ Array[11], Array[11], Array[11], Array[11], Array[11], Array[11], Array[11], Array[11], Array[11], Array[11], 6 more… ].

Comment: @Chris do `var_dump($array)` after you've assigned it in PHP and update your question with the result (or a summary of the result, I need to know how deep the array is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a raw JSON string as your query parameter but are attempting to access it as a named parameter. Updated code:

```
function dataSave(){
outputStr = JSON.stringify(outputData);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "csvout.php",
    data: { outputStr: outputStr },
    dataType: 'html',
});}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<?php    
$array = json_decode($_POST['outputStr']);
adding var_dump($array); here produces NULL

$file = fopen("out/data.csv","w");
foreach ($array as $line){
    fputcsv($file,$item);
}

fclose($file); 
?>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, this does work, but it is saving the data in a single column when opened in Excel, instead of with each nested array as a row. Would there be a simple way to fix that?

Comment: I've made a small update. I still don't know how your data looks like exactly, but if it's just an array of arrays, this should work.